# Preprocessing primary keys in a controller method's model type hinted route parameter

Tags: laravel, dependency-injection, routes, controller, type-hinting

I have some models where I use a custom non-sequential unique id, similar to a standard UUIDs. They are 64 bits long, which should last me over 8000 years, so I store them as an unsigned big integer.

However as a base10 number they are a bit long and unwieldy at 19 digits. To help with this I can transform them into a base36 number (a string containing 0-9 and a-z). They max out at 15 chars, though it should be only 11 or 12 for the next 30 years or so.

My question is whether there is a way to hook into Laravel's type hinted dependency injection so that a constructor method like this:

```php
public function show(ModelName $modelName) {
    dump($modelName);
}
```

with a standard resource route:

```php
Route::get('modelName/{modelName}', 'ModelController@show');
```

will return the correct model when called with a base36 string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly, route binding will solve your problem:

In your `RouteServiceProvider`'s boot function:

```
public function boot()
{
    Route::bind('modelName', function ($value) {
        return ModelName::where('name', $value)->firstOrFail();
    });

    // ...
}
```

Alternatively, if you want to solve it at the model level (maybe with traits) you can override the `resolveRouteBinding` function in your model:

```
public function resolveRouteBinding($value, $field = null)
{
    return $this->where('name', $value)->firstOrFail();
}
```

Source: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#customizing-the-resolution-logic

Comment: This was definitely very helpful, in that I was able to find what I was looking for just underneath the bit you linked to in the documentation. The issue with your solution is that I would have to do it for each model that uses this kind of id. I ended up using `resolveRouteBinding` in a trait (I actually already had a trait for the uids) that I applied to the affected models.

Comment: In addition we were able to overload `forwardsCallTo` in the trait, to hook into the models find method. Laravel 6, which we are using, actually only uses `resolveRouteBinding` for routes with more than one parameter, for a single parameter it just does a find. Since I only asked about laravel in general if you update your answer with the `resolveRouteBinding` method I would like to accept your answer.